# Tag update: sony-vegas to vegas-pro

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

It hasn't been called Sony Vegas for a few years now. We should change the tag to vegas-pro and make sony-vegas a synonym.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good idea.  It has been a while hasn't it. It's done.